# What is ligther, generate a picture within the document using TikZ or import an image, such as a PNG in the document (in general)?

Tags: compiling

Since I use exclusively Overleaf because I'm too afraid my computer dies with all my writings, and Overleaf often warn me that the compilation time almost reached out, I was wondering what is ligther regarding compilation time, create a picture using TikZ or create it in some external tool, like [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/), and then import the generated PNG?

Comment: You could use tikz in a standalone document to create a pdf of the graphic and then import the pdf as image in your document. This way you still have a vector graphic.

Comment: Without seeing what type of graphic you have, it is hard to make a definitive statement, but in general, png is one of the slowest image formats to include, but it still faster than TikZ.

Comment: Regarding the reason of being afraid of losing your documents: there are various solutions for this that do not require Overleaf, such as using cloud storage, or using Git, or making backups on a usb stick etc.

Comment: the results are so massively different it's hard to compare timings, tikz will produce vector images that scale to arbitrary zoom factors. a png is a bitmap at a fixed resolution. It would be better to compare with including pdf or eps.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't thougth about this, interesting... but wouldn't that be even slower?

Comment: @Marijn that's true, I confess that the Overleaf has a simplicity that enchants me

Comment: @Iberis Including a pdf as an image is normally much faster than including a png (unless the pdf has a tremendous amounts of components)

Comment: I have to agree with @Marijn — the real issue here is that you don't have a system for back ups. What happens if Overleaf goes away or gets bought out?